# Using python to interpret results

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to solve the following question.

[image]

Here is my code I have produced

```
import numpy as np
import math
sum = 4
while sum <= 13:
    b = 10**(-sum)
    x = (math.sqrt(9+b)-3)/(b)
    print(x)
    sum +=1
```

which gives the following results

```
0.16666620370475727
0.1666666203714584
0.1666666618049817
0.1666666671340522
0.1666666804567285
0.1666666804567285
0.1666666804567285
0.1666666804567285
0.16653345369377348
0.16431300764452317
```

I am not sure if my code is correct or not. When I plug in 13 for `n` into the original equation in wolfram I am getting something different. I figured as it got closer to 13 it would approach 0.1666666.

Also how would I make a graph from this? I guess this would be the best way to observe my results.

Comment: If you use any calculator for x = 10**(-13), you will get `0.1666666667`. I am sure Wolfram result will have `1.666666e-1`

Comment: @Bazingaa i mean if you plug it into the equation in the image i have included

Comment: Yes, I just entered your equation in a calculator and got this result. Check my answer below

Comment: @Bazingaa is there something wrong with the code i have produced then?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with your code. You just need to save your values in a list to plot them. Since you wrote "how would i make a graph from this", I provided below a complete answer plotting your output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution together with the plot. Explanation: `np.logspace(4, 13, 10)` creates the values of `x` as 10^(4), 10^(5), 10^(6)... 10^(13). You take the inverse of its output to get your desired x-points as 10^(-4), 10^(-5), 10^(-6)... 10^(-13). You then loop over these x-values and solve for your equation. You save the output value for each x in a list and then plot it.

There are other vectorized approaches without having to create a loop. But this should get you started.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xmesh = 1./np.logspace(4, 13, 10)
result = []

for x in xmesh:
    elem = (math.sqrt(9+x)-3)/(x) # removed 'b' because xmesh is already inverse
    result.append(elem) # Adds each element to the list for later plotting

plt.semilogx(xmesh, result, '-bo') # Uses a logarithmic x-axis
plt.gca().invert_xaxis() # Inverts the x-axis because you want it so as per comments
plt.xlabel('1/x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Using your code**

Following is how to make it work using your code without much modification

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sum = 4
xmesh = 1./np.logspace(4, 13, 10)
result = []
while sum <= 13:
    b = 10**(-sum)
    x = (math.sqrt(9+b)-3)/(b)
    result.append(x)
    sum +=1
plt.semilogx(xmesh, result, '-bo')    
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.xlabel('1/x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

**Vectorized approach**

```
import numpy as np

xmesh = 1./np.logspace(4, 13, 10)
result = (np.sqrt(9+xmesh)-3)/(xmesh) # No need to loop. Used `np.sqrt`

plt.semilogx(xmesh, result, '-bo')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

Comment: could you edit your code to make it run from 4 to 13? nevermind just saw your explanation

Comment: What o you mean by 4 to 13? What do you want to plot on x axis?

Comment: well the range goes from 4 to 13 so i would assume this would be the x axis?

Comment: Ok, I reversed the x-axis. It depends on you how you want to present the x-axis.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! what would my code look like if you just added the stuff for the graph?

Comment: yes i will do that now! thanks. When i plug it into my program i get the following output <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7fc06897ff28> shouldnt a graph be printed instead? I have never produced a graph before so i am new to this

Comment: Ok, just put `plt.show()` as the last line of your code. Also don't forget to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. You can also save the figure as `plt.savefig('figure.png')`

Comment: also thank you so much you have really helped me out!

Comment: Yes, two different ways to get the same result. The second one is just a small modification to your code to save the output in a list and plot it. The first one is a bit more direct but not the only alternative. There are many more but that's not the purpose of this post. So I guess it's ok to leave both the codes

Comment: okay well thanks for creating your own and also editing mine. I really appreciate it. Looks like it approaches 0.166666 on the graphs

Comment: I added the third and shortest vectorised approach

Comment: thanks again, the vectorised approach is the next thing I have to learn actually so this comes in handy. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if my code is correct or not.

**Your code is correct.**

What you see is the result of finite precision of floating numbers.

The limit of *`(sqrt(9+x)-3)/x`* for *`x→0`* is *`1/6`* and for moderately small values of *`x`* you have different values that are approaching *`1/6`* BUT
when *`x`* gets really small the numerator is affected by *roundoff* in the result of `math.sqrt`, hence the loss of convergence to the limit value.

For small values of *x* the numerator can be approximated using the binomial approximation, (9+x)^0.5-3= 3*(1+x/9)^0.5-3 ≈ 3*(1+x/18)-3 = 3+x/6-3 = x/6, let's see, using Python, what is really happening

```
>>> for n in range(7,16):
...   x = 10**(-n)
...   print('%2d %10e %s %15e %15e'%(n, x, repr(sqrt(9+x)), sqrt(9+x)-3, x/6))
... 
 7 1.000000e-07 3.0000000166666667    1.666667e-08    1.666667e-08
 8 1.000000e-08 3.000000001666667     1.666667e-09    1.666667e-09
 9 1.000000e-09 3.0000000001666667    1.666667e-10    1.666667e-10
10 1.000000e-10 3.0000000000166667    1.666667e-11    1.666667e-11
11 1.000000e-11 3.0000000000016667    1.666667e-12    1.666667e-12
12 1.000000e-12 3.0000000000001665    1.665335e-13    1.666667e-13
13 1.000000e-13 3.0000000000000164    1.643130e-14    1.666667e-14
14 1.000000e-14 3.0000000000000018    1.776357e-15    1.666667e-15
15 1.000000e-15 3.0000000000000004    4.440892e-16    1.666667e-16
```

I've used `repr(...)` to show the significant digits in the square root result and you can see different concurrent phenomena ① the number of significant digits used to represent *x*/6 is decreasing, ② there is a loss of precision in the calculation of the square root and ③ these *small* effects are amplified by a cancellation effect, as you subtract 3 from a substantially correct result `(3+δ)`.

> Also how would I make a graph from this? I guess this would be the best way to observe my results.

As you can see, it is not necessary to graph the results to gain an insight on the problem!!!

What remains to do, when you have recognized the roundoff caused instability, is to tackle the last part of your question,

> > Is there a better way to evaluate this expression?