# Rewrite an expression to mitigate numerical cancellation

Tags: floating-point

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52459952/2749397), where the OP was asked to find *a better way* to evaluate the following expression

[image]

The limit for *x → 0* of the expression is 1/6 and there is a roundoff error starting from *n* = 12 that gets more significant for *n* = 13.

I scratched my head for a while but I wasn't able to come out with *a better way* to evaluate the previous expression. Using the binomial approximation<sup>1</sup> *is too good* as it gives exactly 1/6 for every value of *x*!!!  Anyone?

---

1: (9+*x*)^0.5-3= 3*(1+*x*/9)^0.5-3 ≈ 3*(1+*x*/18)-3 = 3+*x*/6-3 → (9+*x*)^0.5-3/*x* ≈ 1/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator of the quotient by `sqrt(9+x)+3` and simplify. Then your function becomes

`f(x) = 1/(sqrt(9+x)+3)`

which does not suffer from cancellation and gives a limit of 1/6 for small x.

While this transformation is exact, you can get a slightly simpler but limited approximation if you use the next order of the Taylor expansion

`f(x) ~ 1/6 - 1/216 *x`

The relative error for x=1e-4  would be 0.1543203441e-10.